# count number of user clicks on salesforce

Tags: salesforce

How do I make a workflow to meet this criterion?

When Contact's object records are updated, "Number Of Updates" field will be updated as the following:

This field should count the number of clicks on the "save" button in a specific contact record.

Meaning, in every update, 1 will be added to the field's last value (every update: +1), For example:

Number Of Updates = 5
After saving the Contact's record, "Number Of Updates" field value becomes 6 and so on.

Thanks, Liraz

Comment: Trigger with after update?

Comment: @Thamilan yes , after the user click and the record is saved